# Dropdown button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Referring to the following code, is it possible to change the button so that the action is reverse?
The code immediately shows the menu opened under the word "Click me".

If possible, I would like the button to behave in the opposite way, i.e. start closed and after pressing it open the menu.

```js
function dropIt() {
  toggleClass(document.getElementById('navigation-dropdown'), "hide");
}

function foldIt() {
  toggleClass(document.getElementById('navigation-dropdown'), "hide");
}

function setHeight() {
  var el = document.getElementById('navigation-dropdown');
  el.style.height = el.clientHeight + "px";
}

var toggleClass = function(el, className) {
  if (el) {
    if (el.className.indexOf(className) != -1) {
      el.className = el.className.replace(className, '');
    } else {
      el.className += ' ' + className;
    }
  }
};

setHeight();
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
}

#navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navigation-sub {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #69C;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 15px 7px 15px;
}

#navigation-sub:hover {
  background-color: #C66;
}

#navigation-sub:active {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

#navigation-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: #69C 4px solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 30px;
  /*This here*/
  -webkit-transition: 3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: 3s ease-out;
  transition: 3s ease-out;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0 !important;
}

#navigation-dropdown ul {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navigation-dropdown ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navigation-dropdown ul li a {
  color: #69C;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation-dropdown ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#navigation-dropdown ul li a:active {
  color: #dddddd;
}

#navigation-dropdown input {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="navigation">
    <div id="navigation-sub" onclick="dropIt();">Click me</div>
  </div>
  <div id="navigation-dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link one</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">link two</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">link three</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">link four</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to correct this code or i send you new code with different style?

Comment: You don't need your own `toggleClass` function. What your `function(el, className)` does is exactly equivalent to `if (el) el.classList.toggle(className)`

Answer (score 1):

Just add the hide class onto the navigation-dropdown div:

```
<div id="navigation-dropdown" class="hide">
```

Answer (score 0):

As loop suggested hide class needs to be added but it will create issue of height of dropdown list. so I have adjusted setHeight function and if else condition to make it work perfectly.

```js
function dropIt() {
  toggleClass(document.getElementById('navigation-dropdown'), "hide");
}

function foldIt() {
  toggleClass(document.getElementById('navigation-dropdown'), "hide");
}

function setHeight() {
  var el = document.getElementById('navigation-dropdown');
  el.style.height = el.clientHeight + "px";
}

var toggleClass = function(el, className) {
  if (el) {
if (el.className.indexOf(className) != -1) {
  el.className = el.className.replace(className, '');
   setHeight();
  
} else {
  el.className += ' ' + className;
  el.style.height='';
}
  }
 
};
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
}

#navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navigation-sub {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #69C;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 15px 7px 15px;
}

#navigation-sub:hover {
  background-color: #C66;
}

#navigation-sub:active {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

#navigation-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: #69C 4px solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 30px;
  /*This here*/
  -webkit-transition: 3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: 3s ease-out;
  transition: 3s ease-out;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0 !important;
}

#navigation-dropdown ul {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navigation-dropdown ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navigation-dropdown ul li a {
  color: #69C;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation-dropdown ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#navigation-dropdown ul li a:active {
  color: #dddddd;
}

#navigation-dropdown input {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="navigation">
    <div id="navigation-sub" onclick="dropIt();">Click me</div>
  </div>
 
  <div id="navigation-dropdown" class="hide">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link one</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">link two</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">link three</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">link four</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```